# Azure Devops Pipeline - pass secrets as variables to another job

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to get secret from keyvault using one agent pool in one job and pass them to second job.

```yaml
- job: 'keyvault'
  pool: pool1
  steps:
  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: connection1
      KeyVaultName: keyvault1
      SecretsFilter: '*'

  - powershell: |
      $ID='$(app--id)'
      $secret_var = '$(app--id)'
      echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=secret_var;isOutput=true;]$ID'
    name: secrets

- job: 'job2'
  pool: pool2
  dependsOn: keyvault
  variables:
    secret_var: $[ dependencies.keyvault.outputs['secrets.secret_var'] ]
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        echo $(secret_var)
```

However it does not work. Any idea why? How to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain what actually doesn't work?

I tested this with simples case:

```yaml
jobs:
- job: 'keyvault'
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=secret_var;isOutput=true;isSecret=true;]siema'
    name: secrets

- job: 'job2'
  dependsOn: keyvault
  variables:
    secret_var: $[ dependencies.keyvault.outputs['secrets.secret_var'] ]
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        echo $(secret_var)
```

And it seems to be wroking:

[image]

Comment: Okay, apparently it was due to missing `isSecret=true` parameter... Thank you!